# Azure-Maps Get Search Address Structured API is not giving correct results for 'Michigan,USA'

Tags: azure-maps

I am not getting correct results for 'Mihigan,USA' while using Azure-Maps Get Search Address Structured API with parameter 'countrySubdivision' value as 'MI' or 'Michigan'

I tried below ways but not getting results for only 'Michigan,USA' other states in USA are returning results like AL,WA,WY,NY

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/structured/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key={subscription-key}&countryCode=US&countrySubdivision=MI

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/structured/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key={subscription-key}&countryCode=US&countrySubdivision=Michigan

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/structured/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key={subscription-key}&countryCode=US&countrySubdivision=MI

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/structured/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key={subscription-key}&countryCode=US&countrySubdivision=Michigan

I am expecting results for the 'Michigan,USA' state from Azure-Maps Get Search Address Structured API

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API uses all the query parameters in the request to construct the "query" for the Geocoder. So "MI, USA" will not necessarily understand "MI" (or even "Michigan") as describing the state Michigan and not the "Michigan city" in Indiana (Ideally it should i think). Something like "Michigan state USA" does return some results but I think you'll have to add some location bias like `postalCode` for the api to return more meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

The team has made some improvements around this. Testing the provided queries I'm seeing much more relevant results.